# Recommend Deletion needs another type for Low Quality Posts

Tags: feature-request, review, moderation, low-quality-posts

While most of the people answer the questions on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and most of the time I have found that people do post a single line answer that is actually right however the knowledge on the basis of which the answer has been given is not shared and this is the reason that people ask close to same questions again and again.

Therefore I believe that there should be another type for Low Quality post which has message like this as I saw someone posted that on an answer today.

> While this code snippet may solve the question, including an
>   explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember
>   that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and
>   those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: That's a reason to downvote, not to delete.

Comment: And voting on such posts isn't enough? That is what voting is *for*; if the post is not helpful you vote it down. If the code is actually working that is *still an answer*.

Answer (score 8):

The purpose of the low quality posts queue is to low out only the **really** low quality posts.

A post that's correct but doesn't quite explain itself is indeed low quality, but It's not quite low quality enough to vote for deletion.  I can think of one or two "correct" posts that are low enough quality to delete from that queue, but they're fairly rare.

For more minor quality issues, such as answers not explaining enough, you should upvote or downvote

---

Remember, if you really want to downvote,  you can navigate to the post from the review queue.